# Cant access objects within state

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that uses axios to access the PubMed api (in componentDidMount), retrieves some publication ids then stores them in state as "idlist". A second function is then called (addPapers) which passes in this id list and makes a second api call to retrieve further details (title, journal, authors) for each id. All this seems to work fine and when I use react tools to check state there is an array ("paperList") full of objects that have the expected key:value pairs. However, when I try to map over this array and access the values within the objects in the render function (ie paper.title, paper.author, paper.journal) they are returning as undefined. I haven't been using react for long and suspect I am making a basic mistake but cant figure it out.

I have tried console.logging each step and the expected data is in state and correct in react tools

```
import axios from 'axios'
import './App.css';
import rateLimit from 'axios-rate-limit';

class App extends Component {
  state= {
    idlist: [],
    papersList : ""
  }


  componentDidMount () {
    console.log("incomponent")
     axios.get("https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=json&retmax=1000&term=((Australia%5Bad%5D)%20AND%20(%222019%2F07%2F01%22%5BDate%20-%20Publication%5D%20%3A%20%223000%22%5BDate%20-%20Publication%5D))%20AND%20(%22nature%22%5BJournal%5D%20OR%20%22Nature%20cell%20biology%22%5BJournal%5D%20OR%20%22Nature%20structural%20%26%20molecular%20biology%22%5BJournal%5D)")
    .then (response => 
      this.setState({idlist: response.data.esearchresult.idlist}, () => {
        this.addPapers(this.state.idlist)
      }
    ) 
  )}


    addPapers = (idlist) => {  
      if (idlist) {
        const http = rateLimit(axios.create(), { maxRequests: 6, perMilliseconds: 1000 }) 

        const list = this.state.idlist.map(id => {
          let paperObj ={};
          let paperList =[]
          http.get(`https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=json&rettype=abstract&id=${id}&api_key=9476810b14695bd14f228e63433facbf9c08`)
          .then (response2 => {
          const title = response2.data.result[id].title
          const journal = response2.data.result[id].fulljournalname
          const authorList = []
          const authors = response2.data.result[id].authors
          authors.map((author, idx) =>
            idx > 0 ? authorList.push(" " + author.name) : authorList.push(author.name))
          paperObj.title = title
          paperObj.journal = journal
          paperObj.authors = authorList.toString()
          paperList.push(paperObj) 
          })
          return paperObj
        }) 
        this.setState({papersList: list}) 
      }
    }


  render () {
    let article = ""
    if (this.state.papersList.length){
      article = this.state.papersList.map(paper =>
       console.log (paper.title)
       console.log (paper.authors)
       console.log (paper.journal)
      )
    } 

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Publications</h1>
        {article}
    </div>
  );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I expect that when I map over paperList and extract each paper I should be able to return the title, journal or authors using console.log(paper.title), console.log(paper.title), console.log(paper.title). These are all returning undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues in code

1) `paperList` array declaration should be out of map loop.

2) `paperList` should be returned instead of `paperObj`

Working code below make some enhancements in `render` function

Also [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-panini-u0o3m)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import rateLimit from "axios-rate-limit";
import axios from "axios";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    idlist: [],
    papersList: ""
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("incomponent");
    axios
      .get(
        "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=json&retmax=1000&term=((Australia%5Bad%5D)%20AND%20(%222019%2F07%2F01%22%5BDate%20-%20Publication%5D%20%3A%20%223000%22%5BDate%20-%20Publication%5D))%20AND%20(%22nature%22%5BJournal%5D%20OR%20%22Nature%20cell%20biology%22%5BJournal%5D%20OR%20%22Nature%20structural%20%26%20molecular%20biology%22%5BJournal%5D)"
      )
      .then(response =>
        this.setState({ idlist: response.data.esearchresult.idlist }, () => {
          this.addPapers(this.state.idlist);
        })
      );
  }

  addPapers = idlist => {
    if (idlist) {
      const http = rateLimit(axios.create(), {
        maxRequests: 6,
        perMilliseconds: 1000
      });
      let paperList = [];
      this.state.idlist.forEach(id => {
        let paperObj = {};
        http
          .get(
            `https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=json&rettype=abstract&id=${id}&api_key=9476810b14695bd14f228e63433facbf9c08`
          )
          .then(response2 => {
            const title = response2.data.result[id].title;
            const journal = response2.data.result[id].fulljournalname;
            const authorList = [];
            const authors = response2.data.result[id].authors;
            authors.map((author, idx) =>
              idx > 0
                ? authorList.push(" " + author.name)
                : authorList.push(author.name)
            );
            paperObj.title = title;
            paperObj.journal = journal;
            paperObj.authors = authorList.toString();
            paperList.push(paperObj);
          })
          .then(result => {
            this.setState({ papersList: paperList });
          });
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Publications</h1>
        {this.state.papersList.length &&
          this.state.papersList.map(data => {
            return <div>{data.title}</div>;
          })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: works prefectly - many thanks tarzen! I see you used forEach to loop over data - is there a reason for that instead of .map? And I still dont understand why my attempt to output the data came back as undefined even though I could see that state.paperList looked like it contained the key/value pairs.

Comment: `map` returns array, while `forEach` doesn't and I wasn't returning anything so `forEach`. `paperList` in `addPaper` function contained right data but not in `papersList` as it was not accumulating data in iteration. Go through differences in code and you will figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
render () {
let article;
if (this.state.papersList.length){
  article = this.state.papersList.map(paper => <p>span>Title is {paper.title}</span></p> )
} 



return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Publications</h1>
        {article}
    </div>
  );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Robin but still doesn't work - paper.title is undefined so nothing is returned.